# tkinter code is not running (whatsapp program)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import pywhatkit
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("whatsapp")
root.geometry('405x1000')
root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

label = Label(root, text="Whatsapp Automation", font='bold', width=40 , fg='white',
              bg='black', padx=10, pady=13)
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x=10, y=10)

#form1
label=Label(root, text="whatsapp numbers", font=10 , fg="white", bg="black")
label.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x = 10, y=90)

number_str = StringVar()
entry1 = (Text(root,width=30, textvariable=number_str, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
entry1.insert(0,"+")
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=13)
entry1.place(x=10, y=120)

#form2
label=Label(root, text="الرسالة", font=10 , fg="white", bg="black")
label.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x = 10, y=360)
message_str = StringVar()
entry2 = (Text(root, width=41, textvariable=message_str, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
entry2.insert(0, "write your message")
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=13)
entry2.place(x=10, y=400)

#time
label=Label(root, text="وقت الانتظار24/الساعة", font=20 , fg="white", bg="black")
label.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x = 10, y=450)

labe4=Label(root, font=20 , fg="white", bg="black")
labe4.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
labe4.place(x = 220, y=450)

#time function
def localtime():
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
    labe4.config(text="localtime:"+current_time)
    labe4.after(200, localtime)
localtime()

entry3 = (Entry(root, width=20))
entry3.insert(0, "15")
entry3.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=13)
entry3.place(x=15, y=490)

entry4 = (Entry(root, width=20))
entry4.insert(0, "20")
entry4.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=13)
entry4.place(x=150, y=490)

#whatsapp send

def whatsapp():
    number = entry1.get()
    message = entry2.get()
    time1 = int(entry3.get())
    time2 = int(entry4.get())
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(number, message,time1,time2)

send = Button(root, font="30", width=40, text="ارسال" , fg="black",
              bg="gold" , bd=10,
command=whatsapp)
send.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
send.place(x = 15 , y = 520)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to solve this problem without replacing `Entry` with `Text` in

```
#form1
entry1 = (Text(root,width=30, textvariable=number_str, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
```

and

```
entry2 = (Text(root, width=41, textvariable=message_str, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
```

I can't solve this problem. Code is not running.
The issue's in:

```
entry2 = (Text(root, width=41, textvariable=message_str, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
entry1 = (Text(root,width=30, textvariable=number_str, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
```

Comment: "not running" isn't a specific enough description of the problem. What does happen? Are there any error messages? How do you know where the issue is?

Comment: You cannot set textvariable for Text widget . _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-textvariable" line 21

Comment: exactly 
how i can solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from tkinter import *
import pywhatkit 
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("whatsapp")
root.geometry('405x1000')
root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

label = Label(root, text="Whatsapp Automation", font='bold', width=40 , fg='white',
              bg='black', padx=10, pady=13)
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x=10, y=10)

#form1
label=Label(root, text="whatsapp numbers", font=10 , fg="white", bg="black")
label.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x = 10, y=90)

number_str = StringVar()
entry1 = Text(root,width=30,  bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6)
entry1.insert('end',"+")
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=13)
entry1.place(x=10, y=120)

#form2
label=Label(root, text="الرسالة", font=10 , fg="white", bg="black")
label.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x = 10, y=360)
message_str = StringVar()
entry2 = (Text(root, width=41, bd=6, font=14, borderwidth=6))
entry2.insert('end', "write your message")
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=13)
entry2.place(x=10, y=400)

#time
label=Label(root, text="وقت الانتظار24/الساعة", font=20 , fg="white", bg="black")
label.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
label.place(x = 10, y=450)

labe4=Label(root, font=20 , fg="white", bg="black")
labe4.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
labe4.place(x = 220, y=450)

#time function
def localtime():
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
    labe4.config(text="localtime:"+current_time)
    labe4.after(200, localtime)
localtime()

entry3 = (Entry(root, width=20))
entry3.insert(0, "15")
entry3.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=13)
entry3.place(x=15, y=490)

entry4 = (Entry(root, width=20))
entry4.insert(0, "20")
entry4.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=13)
entry4.place(x=150, y=490)

#whatsapp send

def whatsapp():
    number = number_str.get()
    message = message_str.get()
    time1 = int(entry3.get())
    time2 = int(entry4.get())
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(number, message,time1,time2)

send = Button(root, font="30", width=40, text="ارسال" , fg="black",
              bg="gold" , bd=10,
command=whatsapp)
send.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
send.place(x = 15 , y = 520)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]]